# Rock-paper-scissors Game in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, rock-paper-scissors

Below you will find my first attempt at a C++ implementation of the classic game *Rock-paper-scissors*. If someone could look it over and point out or suggest any things that I could change to improve it, that would be brilliant and I would greatly appreciate it.

#### Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
class Player
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string choice;

    public:
        Player(std::string Name);
        void setName(std::string Name);
        std::string getName() const;
        void setChoice(std::string c);
        std::string makeChoice();
        std::string getChoice() const;
};
#endif
```

#### Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(std::string Name)
{
    name=Name;
    choice=" ";
}

void Player::setName(std::string Name)
{
    name=Name;
}

std::string Player::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

std::string Player::makeChoice()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 3);

    int playerChoice=dis(gen);

    switch(playerChoice)
    {
        case 1:
            choice="rock";
            break;
        case 2:
            choice="paper";
            break;
        case 3:
            choice="scissors";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Please make a valid choice" << std::endl;
            break;
    }
    return choice;
}

void Player::setChoice(std::string c)
{
    choice=c;
}

std::string Player::getChoice() const
{
    return choice;
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include "Player.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void determineWinner(unique_ptr<Player> const & p1, unique_ptr<Player> const & p2)
{
    if(p1->getChoice()=="rock" && p2->getChoice()=="scissors")
    {
        cout << p1->getName() << " wins!" << endl;
    }

    else if(p1->getChoice()=="scissors" && p2->getChoice()=="rock")
    {
        cout << p2->getName() << " wins!" << endl;
    }

    else if(p1->getChoice()=="paper" && p2->getChoice()=="rock")
    {
        cout << p1->getName() << " wins!" << endl;
    }

    else if(p1->getChoice()=="rock" && p2->getChoice()=="paper")
    {
        cout << p2->getName() << " wins!" << endl;
    }

    else if(p1->getChoice()=="scissors" && p2->getChoice()=="paper")
    {
        cout << p1->getName() << " wins!" << endl;
    }

    else if(p1->getChoice()=="paper" && p2->getChoice()=="scissors")
    {
        cout << p2->getName() << " wins!" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "It's a tie!" << endl;
    }
}

void playRockPaperScissors2(unique_ptr<Player> const & p1, unique_ptr<Player> const & p2)
{
    char player1Choice;
    char player2Choice;

    cout << "Player 1, please make your choice:" << endl;
    cout << "Press (r) for rock, (p) for paper, or (s) for scissors" << endl;
    cin >> player1Choice;

    switch(player1Choice)
    {
        case 'r':
            p1->setChoice("rock");
            break;
        case 'p':
            p1->setChoice("paper");
            break;
        case 's':
            p1->setChoice("scissors");
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please make a valid choice" << endl;
            break;
    }

    cout << "Player 2, please make your choice:" << endl;
    cout << "Press (r) for rock, (p) for paper, or (s) for scissors" << endl;
    cin >> player2Choice;

    switch(player2Choice)
    {
        case 'r':
            p2->setChoice("rock");
            break;
        case 'p':
            p2->setChoice("paper");
            break;
        case 's':
            p2->setChoice("scissors");
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please make a valid choice" << endl;
            break;
    }

    cout << "Ready, set" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "rock..." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "paper..." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "scissors..." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "shoot..." << endl;

    cout << p1->getName() << ": " << p1->getChoice() << endl;
    cout << p2->getName() << ": " << p2->getChoice() << endl;

    determineWinner(p1,p2);
}

void playRockPaperScissors(unique_ptr<Player> const & p1, unique_ptr<Player> const & p2)
{
    //Simulates players choosing either rock, paper, or scissors
    string player1Choice=p1->makeChoice();
    string player2Choice=p2->makeChoice();

    p1->setChoice(player1Choice);
    p2->setChoice(player2Choice);

    cout << "Ready, set" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "rock..." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "paper..." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "scissors..." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    cout << "shoot..." << endl;

    cout << p1->getName() << ": " << p1->getChoice() << endl;
    cout << p2->getName() << ": " << p2->getChoice() << endl;

    determineWinner(p1,p2);
}

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Player> player1{new Player("Player1")};
    unique_ptr<Player> player2{new Player("Player2")};

    char modeChoice;

    cout << "Welcome to this simulation of the classic game Rock, Paper, Scissors!" << endl;
    cout << "There are two modes to choose from:" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 for the completely computer simulated version or press 2 if you and a friend want to square off!" << endl;
    cout << "Or, if you've played this game too many times and are sick of it, press (q) to quit" << endl;
    cin >> modeChoice;

    switch(modeChoice)
    {
        case '1':
            playRockPaperScissors(player1,player2);
            break;
        case '2':
            playRockPaperScissors2(player1,player2);
            break;
        case 'q':
            cout << "Program terminating..." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please make a valid choice" << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another post on the same subject. Thought it might be useful. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90588/object-oriented-rock-paper-scissors-game-in-c

Answer (score 10):

You have all the game logic in a single function - `playRockPaperScissors2()`.  If you extracted the logic, you could easily reuse sections of it, perhaps for other games, perhaps to make a computer/human version.

> ```
> cout << "Player 1, please make your choice:" << endl;
> cout << "Press (r) for rock, (p) for paper, or (s) for scissors" << endl;
> cin >> player1Choice;
>
> switch(player1Choice)
> {
>     case 'r':
>         p1->setChoice("rock");
>         break;
>     case 'p':
>         p1->setChoice("paper");
>         break;
>     case 's':
>         p1->setChoice("scissors");
>         break;
>     default:
>         cout << "Please make a valid choice" << endl;
>         break;
> }
> ```

This section in particular is essentially duplicated.  You can create a generic function like this:

```
std::string RPSPlayerChoice() {
    cout << "Please make your choice:" << endl;
    cout << "Press (r) for rock, (p) for paper, or (s) for scissors" << endl;
    cin >> playerChoice;

    do {
        switch(playerChoice)
        {
            case 'r':
                return "rock";
            case 'p':
                return "paper";
            case 's':
                return "scissors";
            default:
                cout << "Please make a valid choice" << endl;
                break;
        }
    while (true);
}
```

If you really want to specify player turn, you could adjust it like this:

```
std::string RPSPlayerChoice(int turn) {
    cout << "Player " << turn << ", please make your choice:" << std::endl;
    cout << "Press (r) for rock, (p) for paper, or (s) for scissors" << std::endl;
    cin >> playerChoice;

    do {
        switch(playerChoice)
        {
            case 'r':
                return "rock";
            case 'p':
                return "paper";
            case 's':
                return "scissors";
            default:
                cout << "Please make a valid choice" << std::endl;
                break;
        }
    while (true);
}
```

You could easily adjust this to be a string name, or any type you want that has an output operator.

One other thing I see is you always use `std::endl`.  `std::endl` flushes the output stream, which can make output unnecessarily expensive.  It is better to force a new line with the `'\n'` new line character, and only flush once when you are done outputting:

```
cout << "Player " << turn << ", please make your choice:\n";
cout << "Press (r) for rock, (p) for paper, or (s) for scissors" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Ah, yes, good point! Could I apply your thinking to my playRockPaperScissors() function as well?

Comment: @xXAnointedXx Sure!  Apply it anywhere the logic is similar!

Answer (score 5):

Some additional tips, mostly focused on performance and maintainability.

- In your `player.h` file you are including multiple headers that you don't really use in that header, such as `<iostream>` and `<random>`. Moving these to the cpp file can save you some compile time for larger projects. If you're only using pointers or references in the header, you can pre-declare them as well.
- Function parameters that are *large* (such as strings, vectors, lists, trees ...) and that you do not modify, are best passed as const references. Currently the function `setName(std::string Name)` will call the copy constructor for this string, while `setName(const std::string& Name)` would not.
- Use initializer lists where possible. With your current constructor of the `Player` class, an empty string for `Name` and `Choice` will be constructed and then the assignment operator for string will be called. Using the following code you construct the object in a single call.

  `Player::Player(const std::string& Name) : name(Name), choice(" ")
  {}`
- (This one is optional as it is personal preference) Generally speaking I like to mark my member variables as such. E.g. `m_Name`, `m_Choice`.
- For large return types, such as in `getName`, feel free to return a const reference. Now you're always returning a copy, which is quite a waste if all you're doing is reading from it.
- String comparisons are more expensive to do than integer or enum compares. So instead of storing the choice in a string, why not use an enum?
- You're allocating two new player objects using new. But looking at there scope there is no need for using new. Just allocate them on the stack using `Player pl1("Player 1");`.
- The function `determineWinner` is going to become troublesome when implementing something like [rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Additional_weapons). Try to solve such a problem with maths rather than brute force. Wikipedia provides an excellent example:

> The majority of such proposed generalizations are isomorphic to a
>   simple game of modulo arithmetic, where half the differences are wins
>   for player one. For instance, rock-paper-scissors-Spock-lizard (note
>   the different order of the last two moves) may be modeled as a game in
>   which each player picks a number from one to five. Subtract the number
>   chosen by player two from the number chosen by player one, and then
>   take the remainder modulo 5 of the result. Player one is the victor if
>   the difference is one or three, and player two is the victor if the
>   difference is two or four. If the difference is zero, the game is a
>   tie.

The comments from the other answers are valid as well - try to avoid copy pasting. If you ever have to copy paste something try to think if it can't be made into a function, macro, class, ...

Comment: I don't know c++, but this looks like a very nice review to me. Welcome to CR!